# Android custom scheme deep links not working on Api 33

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Hi folks I am trying to get me app to handle URLs with a custom schema using the following code

```
<activity
        android:name=".android.DeepLinkActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter android:label="Deep Link">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="myapp"
                android:host="${applicationId}"
                android:pathPrefix="/story" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

This seems to be working when I test it using ADB using the following command

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://com.mycoolapp.debug/story?articleId=abcde"
```

but on a Pixel device when I use the camera application to read a QR code it always opens in Chrome I tried a different browser but it still not working. am I missing something here?

Comment: It seems that google stops support for custom-schemes beginning with android12 for his own camera app; other camera apps still supports custom-schemes. You may drop a bugreport but I think google won't care.

Answer (score 0):

> An Android App Link is a special type of deep link that allows your
> website URLs to immediately open the corresponding content in your
> Android app, without requiring the user to select the app. Android App
> Links use the Digital Asset Links API to establish trust that your app
> has been approved by the website to automatically open links for that
> domain. If the system successfully verifies that you own the URLs, the
> system automatically routes those URL intents to your app.

To verify that you own both your app and the website URLs, complete the following steps:

1. Add intent filters that contain the autoVerify attribute. This attribute signals to the system that it should verify whether your app belongs to the URL domains used in your intent filters.
2. Declare the association between your website and your intent filters by hosting a Digital Asset Links JSON file at the following location:

> https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json